# Magento query how to get category, description and product url

Tags: mysql, category, query, product-urls

This query work ok:

```
SELECT  
    CONCAT(address.firstname,' ', address.lastname) AS Name,
    address.email AS Email,
    items.created_at AS Date,
    items.name AS Description,
    items.store_id AS Logon,
    items.name AS Category,
    items.store_id AS FeedbackDate,              
    items.sku AS ProductSearchcode,
    items.order_id AS Orderref  

FROM sales_flat_order AS orders
    JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS items 
    ON items.order_id = orders.entity_id 
    LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address AS address
    ON orders.entity_id = address.parent_id

WHERE    
    items .created_at BETWEEN  '2014-04-15 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-30 00:00:00'
    AND orders.status = 'complete'
```

But, I also need to get item category, description and url to product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should give you the values for the attributes description and url key plus the categories for each product attached to an order.

```
SELECT  
        CONCAT(address.firstname,' ',
        address.lastname) AS Name,
        address.email AS Email,
        items.created_at AS Date,
        items.store_id AS Logon,
        items.name AS Category,
        items.store_id AS FeedbackDate,              
        items.sku AS ProductSearchcode,
        items.order_id AS Orderref  ,
        IFNULL(store_prod_desc.value,main_prod_desc.value) as Description,
        IFNULL(store_prod_url.value,main_prod_url.value) as Url,
        category_ids.category_id

  FROM sales_flat_order AS orders
  JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS items 
  ON items.order_id = orders.entity_id 
  LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address AS address
  ON orders.entity_id = address.parent_id
  INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_text as main_prod_desc
  ON items.product_id = main_prod_desc.entity_id AND main_prod_desc.attribute_id = 72 AND main_prod_desc.store_id = 0
  LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text as store_prod_desc
  ON items.product_id = store_prod_desc.entity_id AND store_prod_desc.attribute_id = 72 AND store_prod_desc.store_id = orders.store_id
  INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar as main_prod_url
  ON items.product_id = main_prod_url.entity_id AND main_prod_url.attribute_id = 98 AND main_prod_url.store_id = 0
  LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar as store_prod_url
  ON items.product_id = store_prod_url.entity_id AND store_prod_url.attribute_id = 98 AND store_prod_url.store_id = orders.store_id
  INNER JOIN catalog_category_product as category_ids
  ON items.product_id = category_ids.product_id

  WHERE    
  items .created_at BETWEEN  '2014-04-15 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-30 00:00:00'
  AND orders.status = 'complete'
```

Note it does assume that attribute_id 72 is the description and attribute_id 98 is the url_key which is the case for the default attributes